# Windows 7 Title Bar Text Glow

Tags: windows-7, title-bar

When using darker aero themes in Windows 7, the text is given a white glow to make the black title bar text stand out against the semi-transparent background.  Is there a way to remove the glow and change the title bar text to white?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are seeing, but you can try going into the Advanced system settings>Advanced>Visual Effects, and click "Adjust for best performance" just to test. Then if that works, add back only the settings you want. You can see my favorite settings, but I think that you also might need to uncheck "Use visual styles on windows and buttons".

[image]

Comment: Hmm...if you are saying turning off aero will remove the title bar text glow, well yes, that's true.  But I'd prefer to use the W7 themes.

Comment: No, I am just saying test that way. See what you can and cannot live with.

Comment: Yeah, the glow is part of Aero.  There are ways to modify it though through code, but not through settings. . .

Comment: I should have made it more clear that I know it can't be modified through settings.  I'm trying to find out how to modify it some other way.

Comment: @Hodges86 Sorry, that I would not know. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

- Download https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor = [MsstyleEditor.exe]
- Open C:\Windows\Resources\Themes[Theme Name] \ [name.msstyles] file in
  Msstyle Editor.exe
- Go to DWMWindow => Textglow and export the image
- Open the image in Photoshop and remove the white glow and save file as png
- Import the file in the Textglow section and save the msstyles in a
  different name.
- Open the theme file and change the section
- [VisualStyles] Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes[Name of the theme
  ][name of the msstyles file].msstyles
- Save the theme file apply new theme...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can turn off the glow without turning off Aero, as it even has the glow around the Window title caption when you disable Transparency.

Aside from that though, you can change the title text colour pretty easily:

- Right-click Desktop and click "Personalize".
- Click on "Window Color" in "Personalization".
- Click on "Advanced appearance settings..." in "Window Color and Appearance".
- Pick the "Active Title Bar" item in "Window Color and Appearance".
- Change the Font color to whatever you'd like.
- Apply.
- You can then go and pick "Inactive Title Bar", etc. to set additional colours.
- Apply, OK, Save Changes.

Answer (score 0):

To modify Windows 7 Title Bar Text Glow needs a program like "W7 Style builder". This kind of programs used to modify or make custom W7 themes. As it's a bit complicated, I can't say much here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You'll need Aves Vista Style Builder and Photoshop to remove the glow.

When you have AVSB (it's available on a certain site) running

- Click open and find whatever theme you're using.
- Search "glow" in the top right corner and you should see two drop down menus, DWMWindow and TextGlow.
- The one you need to change is the TextGlow **IN** the DWMWindow, not the `<1>` in the TextGlow.
- Click on TextGlow then click Edit, you'll need top open it with Photoshop.
- Use Magic Eraser Tool to erase the image, then save and exit.
- Test it out on AVSB and if it worked click save.

Now, I'm not sure if it's different for each theme but this is what worked with mine.

Comment: Sounds like an ad to me. Please read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). Ads aren't allowed on the stackexchange sites!

Comment: Where is the link?